# Changing colors of smaller JPanels in a pane

Tags: java, jpanel

I am having a problem with using `MouseListener` in order to change the color of a panel, which is among many other similar panels in rows and columns. This is my progress so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.Color.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Checkers extends JFrame implements MouseListener
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        private final int ROWS = 2;
        private final int COLS = 5;
        private final int GAP = 2;
        private final int NUM = ROWS * COLS;
        private int x;
        private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS, GAP,GAP));
        private JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();

        private JPanel [] panel = new JPanel[NUM];
        private Color col1 = Color.RED;
        private Color col2 = Color.WHITE;
        private Color tempColor;

        public Checkers()
        {
            super("Checkers");
            setSize(600,600);
            setVisible(true);
            addMouseListener(this);
            mouseClicked(null);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setBoard();
        }

        public void setBoard()
        // rotates colors on the checkbaord
        {

            for(int x = 0; x < NUM; x++) {
                panel[x] = new JPanel();
                pane.add(panel[x]);
                if (x % COLS == 0) {
                    tempColor = col1;
                    col1 = col2;
                    col2 = tempColor;}
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    panel[x].setBackground(col1);}
                else {
                    panel[x].setBackground(col2);}
            }

            //pane background colour and the size of this pane.
            pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));


            //pane background colour and size of this pane.
            pane2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

            //directions on the board where these panes appear.
            add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);

            pane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            //randomly generate a new color for one of the panes when that pane is clicked.
            int r = random.nextInt(255);
            int g = random.nextInt(255);
            int b = random.nextInt(255);
            setBackground(new Color(r, g, b));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    }
```

**Expected result** - What I'd like to do with this is once one of the red or white panels are clicked, it triggers the `mouseClicked` override and sets the colour of that panel to black (currently set to a random rgb, but doesn't work anyway), so the user knows this has been pressed. The rest of the overrides are left empty as they serve no purpose to me at this moment.

**Current result** - The program executes, but the pane colors don't change once clicked.

Here is the direct image file of what the program looks like when currently executed:

[image: example]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: As a sidenote, the use of the variable `NUM` is not very descriptive. You might want to pick better variable names.

Comment: Will take note of that, thanks.

Comment: `setBackground(new Color(r, g, b));` would set the background of the `Checkers` instance you're running. Instead you'd want to change the background  of the panel that has been clicked. So the easiest way (design wise I'd do it differently) would be to register the mouse listener at each of the tiles (smaller panels) and call `((JComponent)event.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLACK)`. A better design would probably use a model that stores which tile has been clicked and rendering the tiles would then use that model (this might require adjusting the tiles' renderer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better ways to do what you want, but one way is to create a custom `JPanel` class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
}
```

Then instead of creating an array of regular `JPanel`s:

```
private JPanel[] panel = new JPanel[NUM];
```

You can create an array of the custom `JPanel`s:

```
private MyPanel[] panel = new MyPanel[NUM];
```

The custom `JPanel`s all have their own `MouseListener`s so when one is clicked, it updates itself.

Comment: I never knew you could do it that way, I like your approach!

Comment: Is it possible to use these custom JPanels to increment a...'score' maybe? , 1 score for each panel pressed. @LAD

Comment: If you want the `score` variable in your `Checkers` class, just have the `mouseClicked()` method update the variable when called.

Comment: You could make the `score` variable static.

Comment: I have used the `score` variable within `Checkers` , whilst also adding incrementing (Checkers.score++;) inside the `mouseClicked` event within `MyPanel` but the score does not update once a panel is clicked, only once a new object of the GUI is called. why is this?   Eg(clicking 3 panels on the first interface will still conclude a score of 0) but once another interface is opened the score will be 3.

Comment: Are you checking `score` by using `System.out.println()`? If so, where are you calling it? I tested implementing `score` into the code, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried calling score from a public jLabel in Checkers, something like JLabel lbl1 = new JLable ("Score: " + score);

Comment: Ok, the problem is that when the `JLabel` is initialized, `score` is set to `0` at that moment. The panel won't update it's text automatically when `score` is changed.

Comment: Use the `JLabel` method `setText()` to update it's text.

Comment: Okay i've got the incrementation working :D although even if you click on a tile thats already been clicked it will still add on points.

Comment: If you want to have the panel only increment on the first click, just add a `boolean` field to the `MyPanel` class, and have it started off as `false`. Then in the `mouseClicked()` method, have the `boolean` updated to `true`. So, now you can use that `boolean` to check before adding to `score` if the panel has already been clicked or not.